# Uploading Multiple Images using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have the following set up

**view**

```
  <%= form_for([:host, @host_gallery], :url => {:action => "create_photo"}, :html => {:multipart => true, :class => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form'}) do |f| %>


              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :file_name, "Photo:".html_safe,:class => 'col-sm-3 control-label' %>
                <div class="col-sm-8">

                  <%= f.file_field :file_name, :multiple => true, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg' %>
                  <p class="help-block">
                    Choose a large Photo
                  </p>
                  <%= show_errors(@host_gallery, :file_name).html_safe %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ph">Upload Photo</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def create_photo

    params[:host_gallery].each{ |image|
      puts "======================================================"
      puts image.inspect
      puts "==========================END============================"
    }

    # render plain: params.inspect

    @host_gallery = HostGallery.new(host_gallery_params)
    @host_gallery.host_id = current_host.id

    if @host_gallery.save
      redirect_to host_profile_photos_url, notice: 'Photo was uploaded successfully created.'
    else
      flash[:error] = "Event could not be save. Please try again."
      render :new_photo
    end

  end


private

  # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
  def host_gallery_params
    params.require(:host_gallery).permit(:file_name)
  end
```

Now when i try to select multiple images and submit it fails on validation.
In the Console it shows this

```
Started POST "/host/profile/photos/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-11 16:07:44 +0530
Processing by Host::ProfileController#create_photo as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6xo/+KoKHsdQxKYgMpSt337p/z1nIIPwy8aCOb//Qok=", "host_gallery"=>{"file_name"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe409c586c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/y8/g0hc4kb54jq0mlhsqlh6clc40000gn/T/RackMultipart20150911-2195-1edubzs>, @original_filename="AeeSyOb.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"host_gallery[file_name][]\"; filename=\"AeeSyOb.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe409c586a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/y8/g0hc4kb54jq0mlhsqlh6clc40000gn/T/RackMultipart20150911-2195-14vmf57>, @original_filename="10996767_460989807398038_4893798671723861484_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"host_gallery[file_name][]\"; filename=\"10996767_460989807398038_4893798671723861484_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}}
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
======================================================
["file_name", [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe409c586c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/y8/g0hc4kb54jq0mlhsqlh6clc40000gn/T/RackMultipart20150911-2195-1edubzs>, @original_filename="AeeSyOb.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"host_gallery[file_name][]\"; filename=\"AeeSyOb.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe409c586a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/y8/g0hc4kb54jq0mlhsqlh6clc40000gn/T/RackMultipart20150911-2195-14vmf57>, @original_filename="10996767_460989807398038_4893798671723861484_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"host_gallery[file_name][]\"; filename=\"10996767_460989807398038_4893798671723861484_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]]
==========================END============================
Unpermitted parameters: file_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def host_gallery_params
    params.require(:host_gallery).permit(file_name: [:filename])
  end
```

Try this

Comment: You are not allowed to upload nil files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png

Comment: So select files which are of this types

Comment: i did.. select those only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89365/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-ror-developer).

Comment: i this this error "Please Choose a photo." looks like its not able to figure out that two images are being selected. is there anything i need to change in the controller action?